# sql query returning results not in 'between' clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following in a where clause of a select statement:

```
InvoiceDate BETWEEN CONVERT (DATETIME, '01.01.2011', 104) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.08.2011', 104)
```

and I'm receiving results all the way back to 2008.  What's wrong with my query?

Comment: Do you have an `or` condition in your where clause that may be including the additional results?

Comment: There's no reason this shouldn't work.

Comment: Post the entire statement if possible.

Comment: That was it, Jonathan. Made some invalid assumptions about order of boolean operations.

Note to future self/others: always use parentheses to define such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting Jonathan's comment as an Answer so that this question can be answered and come off the unanswered list:

Do you have an or condition in your where clause that may be including the additional results?